# append data in a loop python base condition

Tags: python, pandas

so i have two lists of string say

```
Qt=['Apple', 'Apple', 'orange','orange','orange',  'mango','mango', 'Apple']
```

and

```
Aw = ['1=A', '2=B', '1=Y', '2=N','3=N/A','1=single', '2=married']
```

i would like to have `data['Apple']=['1=A', '2=B']` and `data['orange']=['1=Y', '2=N','3=N/A']`.
the ultimate end goal is to then concatenate them to get `data['Apple']='1=A, 2=B'`
 i have tried a lot of ways i= but can't get it to work. i can print it but cant seem to find a better way to save

```
Qt=['Apple', 'Apple', 'orange','orange','orange',  'mango','mango']
Aw = ['1=A', '2=B', '1=Y', '2=N','3=N/A','1=single', '2=married']
var=list(np.unique(Qt))
ds={}
for n in range(0,len(Qt)):
l =  list([])
for m in range(0, len(var)):
    l.append(var[m])
    if Qt[n]==str(var[m]):
        print var[m], Aw[n]
        l2=l.append(Aw[n])
        ds=l2
```

or if there is an easier way to concatenate the strings on Aw and based on a unique QT i will take it, any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `defaultdict` (im assuming that the extra `Apple` at the end of the `Qt` list is a typo).

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> d = defaultdict(list)
>>> for k, v in zip(Qt, Aw):
        d[k].append(v)

>>> d['Apple']

['1=A', '2=B']
```

Comment: yep it does it well. you have know idea how much you have helped me right now. thank you very much!